# Form is squeezing to button width

Tags: html, forms, user-interface, button, webix

I'm trying to create a simple Webix form, but there's a problem: when adding a button (regardless or its position - inside the form or out of it), the whole form is squeezed to the button width. Here's my code:

```
webix.ui({ 
  container:"form",
  rows:[    
    { view:"form", elements:[
      { view:"text", label:"Name" },
      { view:"text", label:"Email" },
      { view:"text", label:"Password" }
    ] },
    { view:"button", autowidth:true, value:"Submit" }
    ]
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/89628ea1

Wondering how it can be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the property width in the form.

```
{ 
  container:"form", width:300,
  rows:[    
    { view:"form", elements:[
      { view:"text", label:"Name" },
      { view:"text", label:"Email" },
      { view:"text", label:"Password" }
    ] },
    { view:"button", autowidth:true, value:"Submit" }
    ] 
}
```